# SEO-Friendly 3 column layout

Tags: html, css

I need to layout a site that has three columns in this order:

```
leftColumn | mainColumn | rightColumn
```

leftColumn and rightColumn are both advert columns, and the mainColumn section contains all the SEO-rich content.

Therefore in the code I have placed the divs used for the layout in the following order so that the main content is seen first for SEO benefit:

```
<div id="mainColumn">
</div>
<div id="leftColumn">
</div>
<div id="rightColumn">
</div>
```

I have also done it this way so that if the user is browsing the page from a mobile they will see the main content first, not the adverts.

So my question is, how do style the columns so that they display in the correct order?
This is an HTML5 / CSS3 page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as a starting point:

```
<div id="mainColumn" class="column">1</div>
<div id="leftColumn" class="column">2</div>
<div id="rightColumn" class="column">3</div>
```

```css
.column {
    position:relative;  
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
#mainColumn {
    width:50%;
    left:25%;   
}
#leftColumn {
    left:-50%;  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bn3t8/

This code is very basic and probably requires IE fixes and support for full-height backgrounds on the columns. You might want to check out this site for some more defensive strategies (highly recommend):

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm